# Pasar información entre actionResults

Tags: asp.net

### Pasar información entre actionResult pero no por URL

Quisiera saber como hago para pasar información entre las acciones, pero no por URL ya que si necesito pasar una lista no se podría de este modo.

algunas sugerencias si esto no es posible?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este casos si realizas un `RedirectToAction` de un action a otro podrias usar el `TempData`

[Using TempData in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786603/Using-TempData-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

de esta forma podrias pasar datos de un action a otro

```
public ActionResult TemporaryEmployee()
{
    Employee employee = new Employee
    {
            EmpID = "121",
            EmpFirstName = "Imran",
            EmpLastName = "Ghani"
    };
    TempData["Employee"] = employee;
    return RedirectToAction("PermanentEmployee");
}

 public ActionResult PermanentEmployee()
{
   Employee employee = TempData["Employee"] as Employee;
   return View(employee);
}
```

en el ejemplo aplica lo que comento

Nota: el ejemplo se obtuvo del articulo del link

Answer (score 0):

pues lo que haria yo es pasar la info por sessiones y al recibir la info borrar las variables de session.